# Turn off Auto Build in Eclipse CDT directly on files in Workspace metadata

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-metadata

How to turn off Auto Build feature in Eclipse CDT, using metadata files in WorkSpace directory for the project without using any dialog boxes and window wizards.

Any file under project workspace "/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects" would contain such information, which can be easily edited and preserved?

My use case is, to create a project workspace template, which is preconfigured with custom settings, and must be used by different users.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable autobuild from Preferences->Workspace and uncheck Build automatically.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kometen, Sorry I should have explained my question with more details.

I was looking to avoid dialog boxes and wizards. Instead make the change directly in the files under "metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/"  work space.

Is there any file under metadata to edit, so that Auto Build is swithced off

Comment: @Satya Thank you. I did thought of it back then when answering. I found a file workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi. If you open the file and search for buildAutomatically there is a category. But I don't know the inner workings of Eclipse well enough unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

### edit workspace

You can make a template workspace by adding to the `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs` file:

```
description.autobuilding=false
```

and then zip up your workspace and request developers use it as a starting point. The [DAWN project](http://www.dawnsci.org/) provides [template workspaces](http://www.opengda.org/buckminster/templates/) with auto-build off and recommends using them in the [Developer Guidelines](http://www.dawnsci.org/documentation/developer-guidelines#TOC-2.-Clean-workspace).

### plugin_customization.ini

The traditional way to do this is with `plugin_customization.ini`.

Create a file called `plugin_customization.ini` with these contents:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources/description.autobuilding=false
```

Then you add `-pluginCustomization <path to>/plugin_customization.ini` to your command line or the following to your eclipse.ini.

```
-pluginCustomization 
<path to>/plugin_customization.ini
```

This makes every new workspace you create override the default preference values with those preference settings.

You can even include `plugin_customization.ini` in your [Eclipse Product plug-in](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_def_extpt.htm?cp=2_0_21_0_0).

### Oomph

However all that said, [Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer), aka The Eclipse Installer, was designed exactly for the use case you are describing. It is designed to make it a few clicks for a new engineer to get started, or an existing engineer to spin a new workspace or configuration. From the above url:

> Non-exhaustive list of features:
>
> - Provisioning correct set of plugins in the Eclipse IDE.
> - Binding Git
>     repos (incl. personal Gerrit push URL).
> - Checking out projects.
> - Setting
>     workspace preferences.
> - Configuring [Dynamic Working Sets](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Dynamic_Working_Sets).
> - Keeping
>     project preferences files in sync.
>
> The configuration is model driven,
>   with the possibility to customize a lot for each project, each branch,
>   each user…